# SQL Function for On Balance Volume (Financial Query)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to create a function for On Balance Volume (SQL Function).
This is too complex of a calculation for met to figure out but here is the outline of the User Defined Table Function.  If someone could help me to fill in the blanks I would appreciate it.
Craig

```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStdDev3] (@TKR VARCHAR(10))
   RETURNS @results TABLE (
    dayno   SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [date]  DATETIME
    , [obv] FLOAT
    )
    AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @rowcount SMALLINT
     INSERT @results ([date], [obv])

// CREATE A FUNCTION FOR ON BALANCE VOLUME
// On Balance Volume is the Summ of Volume for Total Periods
// OBV = 1000 at Period = 0
// OBV = OBV Previous + Previous Volume if Close > Previous Close
// OBV = OBV Previous - Previous Volume if Close < Previous Close
//  OBV = OBV Previous if Close = Previous Close

//  The actual Value of OBV is not important so to keep the ratio low we reduce the 
// Total Value of Tickers by 1/10th or 1/100th
// For Value of Volume = Volume * .01 if Volume < 999
// For Value of Volume = Volume * .001 If Volume >= 999
    FROM Tickers

   RETURN

    END
```

This is the Tickers table

```
 [dbo].[Tickers](
 [ticker] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [date] [datetime] NULL,
 [high] [float] NULL,
 [low] [float] NULL,
 [open] [float] NULL,
 [close] [float] NULL,
 [volume] [float] NULL,
 [time] [datetime] NULL,
 [change] [float] NULL
 )
```

Here is an example of the data

```
   ticker  date  close  volume 
   pzi:  5-10-10  10.94    805 
   pzi;  5-11-10  11.06    444 
   pzi:  5-12-10  11.42    236 
   pzi:  5-13-10  11.3    635 
   pzi:  5-14-10  11    316 

   date  obv 
   5-10  996.38 
   5-11  996.82 
   5-12  997.06 
   5-13  996.42 
   5-14  996.11
```

Comment: I do not see a column for Period, are the periods sequentially based on date? Can you give us some sample data and sample output that illustrates each of the scenarios?

Comment: Also, what database product and version are you using?

Comment: The periods are just the dates...  (All dates for the query or all dates for the available data).  I am using SQL 2005.  An example of OBV using data for the following ticker table and output is as follows...

Comment: ticker    date      close    volume
     pzi:       5-10-10   10.94    805
     pzi;       5-11-10   11.06    444
     pzi:       5-12-10   11.42    236
     pzi:       5-13-10   11.3     635
     pzi:       5-14-10   11       316

     date     obv
     5-10     996.38
     5-11     996.82
     5-12     997.06
     5-13     996.42
     5-14     996.11

Comment: ticker    date      close    volume\
     pzi       5-10-10   10.94    805
     pzi       5-11-10   11.06    444
     pzi       5-12-10   11.42    236
     pzi       5-13-10   11.3     635
     pzi       5-14-10   11       316

     date     obv
     5-10     996.38
     5-11     996.82
     5-12     997.06
     5-13     996.42
     5-14     996.11

Comment: @CraigJSte Your example results and data don't give enough information, since it doesn't show day 0 at 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working inline table valued function (most efficient for the optimizer):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStdDev3] (@TKR VARCHAR(10))
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN (
    WITH    Y AS ( SELECT   *
                   ,OBV_Change = ISNULL(SIGN(currclose - prevclose)
                                        * volume, 1000)
           FROM     ( SELECT    curr.date
                               ,curr.[CLOSE] AS currclose
                               ,prev.[CLOSE] AS prevclose
                               ,curr.volume
                      FROM      Tickers AS curr
                      LEFT JOIN Tickers AS prev
                                ON prev.ticker = @TKR
                                   AND prev.date = ( SELECT MAX(date)
                                                     FROM   Tickers
                                                     WHERE  ticker = @TKR
                                                            AND date < curr.date
                                                   )
                      WHERE     curr.ticker = @TKR
                    ) AS X
         )
SELECT  y1.date
       ,SUM(y2.OBV_Change) AS OBV
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y1.date) AS dayno
FROM    Y AS y1
LEFT JOIN Y AS y2
        ON y2.date <= y1.date
GROUP BY y1.date
)
```

I wasn't sure about the normalization - I left that out - adding it in might need you to make this in to a multi-statement TVF.

Comment: Cade, When I try to run this it give me an error regarding the Order By Clause - saying its invalid unless you use TOP, etc.  any suggestions?  Also, I am not sure what you mean by normalization... good work though!  I have'nt quite figured out how the logic but if you could clear up a few issues for me I'll try to figure it out!

Comment: Create Function should say dbo.OBV not GetStdDev

Comment: I took out the bottom Order By Clause... Not sure this is exactly the right data... I think you are multiplying the difference in Close Value and we only need to add or subtract the Volume (can we multiply volume by .0001 first?).  I initially said .001 but it would be better to use 0001.

Comment: @CraigJSte Sorry, I inserted it into the function after testing the code - you will need to SELECT FROM udf ORDER BY dayno.  I am only using the SIGN of the difference to multiply by the volume.  If the normalization is done per row and not per set, then yes, you can just divide by 1000 on each row.

Comment: I think this will work... I just added volume / 1000 to OBV_Change expression